# gdborig.exe crashes randomly when debugging QT 5.8 and opening QFileDialog in windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gdb, qt5

I'm using Qt 5.8, with clion as IDE, made with bundled cmake 3.7.2.  Using Mingw-w64, x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0, which came  bundled with GDB 7.11.1.  Using Qt5.8 version from msys2 supposedly compiled with the same version of mingw-64 (couldn't get QT to compile on my system, so that was my only option). This problem seems agnostic to what I'm doing specifically, I'll often have code that works perfectly, no crashes, segfaults or whatever, and when i do the same things in the debugger it hangs for 30 seconds trying to open the `QFileDialog`, slowly loading the gui as if its going to work, before quickly crashing saying "Gdborig.exe has stopped working".

Not sure what other context I can provide, as again, only appears after doing the following calls:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(m_parent, QObject::tr("Save File"), QString(), QObject::tr("*");
```

but it doesn't matter what static method I use, same thing happens on `getOpenFileName`, and `getOpenFileNames`.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern strictly speaking to the crashing, there are times I can get past it, and there are times I couldn't.  I originally had a hypothesis that because I was using `-pg -Og` flags when the issue first appeared that these caused the issue, but I have since removed both of these flags and the issue persists.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: @m7913d how do I get a stack trace of this if I'm not using MSVC?

Comment: I don't know clion, but you will probably be able to debug your program with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen similar behaviour in otherwise perfect applications and I was able to work around this by adding `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` as final parameter to the QFileDialog calls.
So I think, this is a COM-apartement issue of the native Windows libraries. But I have to admit, this is a very wild guess.

Comment: didn't need to test this until now, this appears to solve the issue, Already up-voted before so I'll mark this as answer.